# Parsing string with C - whats the right tool?

Tags: c, string, parsing

I got a string in this format:

```
Stuff: </value_1/value_2/value_3>; key="value"
```

What I need parsed out is `value_1`, `value_2` and `value_3` along with the `key`/`value` pair. `value_3` might or might not be present in the string.

What would one use in C in order to get this done?

I thought about `sscanf` but the values can be of arbitratry size, so they should be allocated dynamically. `strtok` would have been my next idea, but that probably needs two separate loops to extract the `/` separated values and the `key`/`value` pair… seems tedious but at least doable.

Anyone with more experience in C has any better idea?

EDIT: regex could be an option, but I would prefer standard string functions if possible at all.

Comment: **If** the format is completely fixed and unambiguous, you could consider using a regex library.

Comment: What type are `value_1` etc. - strings or integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `"</>; =\""` as the delimiter set, then strtok() will work in a single pass, extracting in turn:

```
Stuff:
value_1
value_2
value_3
key
value
```

Not sure what `Stuff:` is or if it is needed in the extraction, or just an elidation on your part.

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions; see [Regular Expressions - The GNU C Library](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Regular-Expressions.html).

If you don't know what regular expressions are; see [Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Here's an online [regular expression editor](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) (or [this one](http://rubular.com/), if you don't have Flash installed), so you can test your regexp!